# Replacing all element's click bindings with a single document.on('click')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, onclicklistener, dom-events

I've always added click listeners to every separate element that needs to be listened, which can create a big messy Javascript with a lot of event bindings.

I was now thinking of doing it another way; by binding the click event to the entire document and upon click, see if the targeted element has a 'data-action' attribute and if present, execute the function in it. So that clicking:

```
<a href="#" data-action="ajax_load_stuff"></a>
```

Will execute function `ajax_load_stuff()`

It would make my code much cleaner, especially in ajax environments, but I want to know about performance and efficiency of this method. Are there any disadvantages to this approach?

---

UPDATE code example:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target) {
        var action = e.target.getAttribute("data-action");
        if (action) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var params = e.target.getAttribute("data-params");
            var data = [];
            if (params) {
                data = params.split(',');
            }
            window[action].apply(e.target, data);
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse this approch has several advantages and disadvantages.

First discussing the disadvantages.

1. Need to handle **event propagation** perfectly otherwise it could make your system slow.
2. Passing parameter to click event will be difficult. Maybe need to introduce another attribute like : **data-action-param**

Advantages:

1. Less event handling code.

Comment: I see, so as long as I prevent propagation to any parent element from the target (so data-action attribute is checked only on 1 element), this method would work well? Do you have any idea about whether this would work faster or slower in a document with for example 5000 buttons? Compared to separate event binding

Comment: Check out https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html under "develop smart event handlers" for more information on the topic

Comment: Do you know any performance test results for delegating events to the entire document with a large DOM? as i described in the above comment